# Summing up a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Item, Quantity
FROM aTable
WHERE Item LIKE '%ABC%'
```

I would like to have a row at the end summing up the `Quantity` column. I tried:

```
GROUP BY 
    Item ROLLUP(Quantity)
```

but I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near 'RollUp'

What syntax would be to get this result?

Do I have to do two queries and join the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the total aggregate you also need to actually put an aggregate in your `SELECT`. Without doing that, SQL Server won't know what to aggregate.

As you only have 2 columns, either `GROUP BY ROLLUP (Item)` or `GROUP BY Item WITH ROLLUP` will work, with the `Quantity` in a `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT Item,
       SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM (VALUES('apple',2),
            ('pear',3),
            ('cheese',1),
            ('potato',9))V(Item,Quantity)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Item);

SELECT Item,
       SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM (VALUES('apple',2),
            ('pear',3),
            ('cheese',1),
            ('potato',9))V(Item,Quantity)
GROUP BY Item WITH ROLLUP;
```

Alternatively, you could use `GROUPING SETS` which some, myself included, prefer (especially if you have more columns and only want some totals). To get the same results as the above queries would be the following:

```sql
SELECT Item,
       SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM (VALUES('apple',2),
            ('pear',3),
            ('cheese',1),
            ('potato',9))V(Item,Quantity)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (Item, ());
```

Comment: That's not strictly true, you can do `GROUP BY Item, ROLLUP(Quantity)` which is the equvalent of `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (Item, Quantity), (Item) )`. Also `WITH ROLLUP` is deprecated

Comment: Good point, @Charlieface . I tend to not use `ROLLUP` and use `GROUPING SETS` and misread the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax uses a comma

```sql
GROUP BY 
    Item,
    ROLLUP(Quantity)
```

This is the equivalent of the following, which is much clearer

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (Item, Quantity),
  (Item)
)
```

Although given your description, you actually want just a grand total

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (Item, Quantity),
  ()
)
```

Comment: I must admit, I'm not sure that that will give the correct results the OP is after. We don't have sample data, I admit, but with the sample data from my own answer, this just ends up duplicating the rows.

Comment: It duplicates the `Item` rows with a `NULL` or summed quantity https://dbfiddle.uk/dHk7dHSg You obviously need multiple `Item, Quantity` pairs to start with, which you didn't have

Comment: My understanding is the OP wants a "grand total" from their statement: *"I would like to have a row at the end summing up the `Quantity` column."*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if there is only one item it will otherwise appear as there are duplicate rows:

```
SELECT Item, grouping(Quantity) as Aggregated_items,
       SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM (VALUES('apple',2),
            ('pear',3),
            ('cheese',1),
            ('potato',9),
            ('potato',13)
  ) V(Item,Quantity)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (Item, Quantity),
  (Item)
);
```

grouping(Quantity) will be 1 for the grouping set (Item) and 0 for (Item, Quantity)

```
Item    Aggregated_items    Quantity
apple   0                   2
apple   1                   2
cheese  0                   1
cheese  1                   1
pear    0                   3
pear    1                   3
potato  0                   9
potato  0                   13
potato  1                   22
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mto0gSER)

Normally you would have something that distinguishes one kind of apple from another (could be a sale-date, kind of apple etc). If that attribute is a string type, a common pattern is to use COALESCE:

```
SELECT ITEM, COALESCE(KIND_OF_ITEM, 'Total'), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in two different query blocks and use "UNION ALL" to combine them as follows:

```
SELECT Item, Quantity
FROM aTable
WHERE Item LIKE '%ABC%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total Item' as Item, sum(Quantity)
FROM aTable
WHERE Item LIKE '%ABC%'
```

Comment: Correct Query

SELECT Item, Quantity
FROM aTable
WHERE Item LIKE '%ABC%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total Item' as Item, sum(Quantity)
FROM aTable
WHERE Item LIKE '%ABC%'

Comment: This does not satisfy the "at the end". PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.